# Information theoretic alternative to tf-idf heuristic?

Tags: text-mining, information-theory

I've been recently working with feature construction from texts, where tf-idf measure is one of the main options for vectorizing the documents (one feature per e.g., word). I was wondering, whether there exists an information-theoretic alternative?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, I figured out that constructing word embeddings at the end solved the problem, although this is not the symbolic way I wanted.